# How to insert text into input prompt using ZSH ZLE

Tags: shell, zsh

I'd like to have a keybinding, that would paste text at the cursor within a prompt.

For example:

> Prompt: `ls _`
>
> Press CTRL-Z
>
> Prompt: `ls textGoesHere`

I'm creating a ZSH ZLE widget, but I can't figure out how to achieve the above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the command buffer from within widgets with the parameters `BUFFER`, `LBUFFER` and `RBUFFER`. `BUFFER` contains the whole command, while `LBUFFER` only contains the part left of the current cursor position and `RBUFFER` the part to the right of the cursor. These parameters can also be modified.

If you want to insert some text at the cursor position, you can just prepend the desired text to `RBUFFER`:

```sh
addText () {
    text_to_add="textGoesHere"
    RBUFFER=${text_to_add}${RBUFFER}
}
zle -N addText
bindkey '^Z' addText
```

Comment: Using `RBUFFER="${text_to_add}${RBUFFER}"` does not move the cursor position forward over the inserted text. Instead, the text is inserted after the cursor, leaving the cursor position unchanged. To insert the text at cursor position, but move the cursor forward over the inserted chars, use: `LBUFFER+="${text_to_add}"`.